# GCP Cloud Build - How to read topic data in the cloudbuild

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

GCP Cloud Build - How to read topic data in the cloudbuild

We are using pubsub to trigger the cloudbuild , now we need to read the data in the pubsub topic that triggered the cloud build

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this  [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automate-builds-pubsub-events?generation=2nd-gen) on How to automate builds in response to Pub/Sub events.

As suggested in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automate-builds-pubsub-events?generation=2nd-gen#:%7E:text=body.message.attributes.eventType) make sure that the format of these messages indicates the real data is `body.message.data`, and that [PubsubMessage](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessag) is accessible as `body.message`.

And also as per [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-bash-and-bindings-in-substitutions#payload_bindings)

> You can store parts of your trigger's event payload as a substitution variable value. Payload bindings are available as variable values for builds invoked by push and pull events, and can be used to access the JSON payload when your source code is in GitHub repositories or Cloud Source Repositories.

You can use the  [payload bindings](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-bash-and-bindings-in-substitutions#payload_bindings) and [user defined substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions) to parse the payload info.